# when is null show custom text other wise show id

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a query I can't seem to get it to show 'no project' when there is no matching project id:

```
(select (case when prj.Proj_ID is null or prj.Proj_ID =  '' 
    then 'No Project' 
    ELSE prj.Proj_ID + ', ' + prj.[DESC] 
    END) 
from prj 
where prj.Proj_ID = other.Proj_ID)  as 'Project Description'
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You also should check whether the project description is null, otherwise you might get back null when you concatenate `prj.Proj_ID + ', '` with it:

```
SELECT CASE
         WHEN prj.Proj_ID IS NULL
               OR prj.Proj_ID = '' THEN 'No Project'
         ELSE prj.Proj_ID + COALESCE(', ' + prj.[DESC], '')
       END AS 'Project Description'
FROM   prj
       LEFT OUTER JOIN other
         ON prj.Proj_ID = other.Proj_ID
```

(I've also done it so if the description is null, it won't display the comma either)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
  CASE WHEN (prj.Proj_ID IS NULL OR prj.Proj_ID = '') THEN 'No Project'
    ELSE prj.Proj_ID + ', ' + prj.[DESC]
  END as 'Project Description'
FROM
  other
  LEFT JOIN prj on prj.Proj_ID = other.Proj_ID
```

If you're joining to PRJ from OTHER database, you'll need to left join to it. If the Proj_ID is not found in the PRJ table, the case statement will return 'No Project'. The parenthesis will help in resolving the conditional statement for `prj.Proj_ID`.

In your original query, you don't seem to specify which table you're joining, yet indicate a join by the statement `where prj.Proj_ID = other.Proj_ID)  as 'Project Description'`.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
SELECT
  CASE WHEN (other.Proj_ID IS NULL OR other.Proj_ID = '') THEN 'No Project'
    ELSE other.Proj_ID + ', ' + prj.[DESC]
  END as 'Project Description'
FROM
  other
  LEFT JOIN prj on ISNULL(prj.Proj_ID,0) = ISNULL(other.Proj_ID,0)
```